# When attempting to open some MS Word Docs I'm asked to download - STHeiti and other fonts

Tags: macos, ms-office, font

When opening one of my documents in Word 2011 on MacOS 10.12.3, I'm asked to download a series of fonts including: STHeiti and Osaka.

I assume this means the document was opened on a computer with those fonts installed and now the file is convinced they need to exist.

I've tried accepting the downloads but the problem just returns the next time I reboot my mac.

So where should these fonts be installed and where is Office installing them?

Comment: Do they show up in Font Book?

Comment: Interesting, the two I could immediately think of were not. I went to FontBook - their names were present but greyed out. I download the fonts and now I just need to wait and see if that's cured the problem for at least these two fonts.

Comment: If they're greyed out, you'll need to right click them and enable them.

Comment: Sorry - yes and to enable I had to download via fontbook. Now the question is - did that have any more effect than MS-Office's download. I suspect I will only know when the other person edits and resaves the shared document.

Answer (score 17):

The solution was hinted at in the comments.

1. Open FontBook: 
   Launch `Font Book.app` (located in the `Applications` folder).
2. Find the fonts in question: 
   Select "All fonts" in the sidebar and search for them using the search box in the upper-right corner of the window. Once found, each will be greyed out.
3. Download the font:
   Either press the "Download" button in upper-right corner of the preview pane or right-click the font to display the context menu and select "Download".
4. Smile now that MS Office doesn't ask you skip/download whenever you open that doc again.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not seem to be permanent solution for me: if I download the fonts with FontBook, Word stops asking me for about one or two weeks (I haven't found the pattern yet) then starts asking for these fonts again every time I open a document with formulas. I have Mac OS 10.12.6 and MS Word 14.5.2. Also, I cannot find where on my mac these fonts are so I can make backup copies and just replace them manually whenever this happens, instead of having to download them each time. Any help would be very welcome.

Comment: Agreed with @RoberRM's comment, this has happened a couple time to me as well. The requests keep coming back. The answer is a good workaround but better yet would be to somehow disable the request from ever coming at the Word level. Is it a special option that is requiring these font packs? In my case, they are all asian character sets (Osaka, STheiti, STKaiti, STFangsong). Thanks for any tips

Comment: Even worst, in some cases the download fails, with some error message asking to try the download again later...